# LVM - Moving data between Logical Volumes within the same Physical Volume

Tags: redhat, lvm, copy

I will have two logical volumes that exist within one physical volume (RedHat Linux LVM).

I will also be moving a lot of data between these LVs.

My question is: Does the data get moved on the actual physical disk or is it only the file path that is changed?

Setup:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                   |
|                                     +                                             |
|                                     |                                             |
|     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+   |
|     |                               |                                         |   |
| PV  |    +--File---+                |                                         |   |
|     |    +-+----+--+        +       |        +                                |   |
|     |                       |       |        |                                |   |
|     +-------------------------------------------------------------------------+   |
|                             |       |        |                                    |
|                             |       |        |                                    |
|     +----------------------------+  |        |                                    |
|     |                       |    |  |        |                                    |
| LV1 |                       v    |  |        |                                    |
|     |                            |  |        |                                    |
|     +----------------------------+  |        |                                    |
|                                     |        |                                    |
|                                     |        |                                    |
|                                     |    +------------------------------------+   |
|                                     |    |   |                                |   |
| LV2                                 |    |   v                                |   |
|                                     |    |                                    |   |
|                                     |    +------------------------------------+   |
|                                     |                                             |
|                                     +                                             |
|                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Which OS are you dealing with?

Comment: Linux Redhat, I still don't know which version it will be.

Comment: It gets moved.  If it were otherwise, and the blocks were just de-assigned from the source volume and re-assigned to the destination volume, the relative sizes of the volumes would be constantly changing, and it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "move" I assume you are talking about using `cp` or `mv` to move data from one LV to another, not taking snapshots. In that case, the data is physically moved on disk.